# Debug doesn't work with library references - Errormsg "Cant enter break mode at this time"

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a macro in Excel VBA to make users send their Excel-File via E-Mail automatically back to me.
To use this macro every user must install the Outlook Library. For this I created the function add_outlook. **If I try to run the function it works.**
The only problem occurring is that VBA doesn't let me debug. **When stepping through the code I get the Errormsg "Cant enter break mode at this time"**

Is there a workaround or fix?

Thanks a lot!

```
Option Explicit
Public Function add_outlook()


'DEBUGGING DOESNT WORK
'late binding
Dim vbProj As Object
Set vbProj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
Dim vbRefs As Object
Set vbRefs = vbProj.References
Dim vbRef As Object

'Libary GUID and Data
Dim libname As String
libname = "Outlook"
Dim guid As String
Dim major As Long
Dim minor As Long
Dim exists As Boolean
guid = "{00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
major = 9
minor = 6


'Reference cleanup function
For Each vbRef In vbRefs
    If vbRef.Name = libname Then

'problem occurs here
        vbRefs.Remove Reference:=vbRef
    End If
Next

'add Ref
vbRefs.AddFromGuid guid:=guid, major:=major, minor:=minor
End Function
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint after the part that can't be debugged and step [again] from there.

Comment: References are stored with the macro workbook so you don't need to do this. If you have to worry about different versions of Outlook, use late binding.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Setting Breakpoints didnt prevent the error to happen. On error resume next doesnt work too.

Comment: @Rory yes I used late binding. The code works like I said.  I am still curious, why the error is happening when debugging

Comment: You can't step through code that changes the VBA project (you'll get the same error for example if you try and step through code that adds activex controls to a sheet). FYI, I meant late bind your code so you don't need an Outlook reference at all, not late bind the code to add the reference.

Comment: Yeah, a lot of things from the VBIDE library will throw that error as many methods in there alter the Project. You can change references whenever you want, but has to execute and you can't Step through it. Or, if you use late binding (Dim **this** as **Object** then, Set **this** = CreateObject("Lib/Class")). For me, I stay away from using exact versions (major/minor/GUID), I like to AddFromFile as the file path would be the same with minor folder name difference (Ex: \VBA\VB7\ or \VBA\VB7.1\)

Comment: Many thanks for all the answers! Sadly i have still not enough reputation to upvote your comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call add_outlook
End Sub
```

- Cant step through code
- Get reference when Workbook_open event is triggered